# Pure java video endcoding/decoding libraries

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know of any video encoding/decoding libraries written entirely in java?
Bonus points if it works on Android.

I'm trying to write a video decoding application for android, where I have access to the frame level decoding functions (which is absent in the android API MediaPlayer class)

Comment: On Android 4.1 one might have a look at the MediaCodec API.

Answer (score 4):

jcodec is a pure java implementation of audio and video codecs and containers. Currently, it "only" decode H264 (MPEG-4) and MJPEG. More informations [here](http://jcodec.org/).

Comment: JCodec decodes a few more codec now including VP8 and AAC.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to look at this :
http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/tk4mpeg4 (looks fairly old though)

But (depending on your platform), I believe you will have a hard time for a real time decoder purely in Java...

Comment: Yes I agree. Xuggler uses JNI wrappers, and even then it's still got problems. I'm interested to hear from anyone who's actually done audio/video in Java. Xuggler has sync issues.