# Frame by frame Video processing in Java

Tags: java, video

I am working on an app that adds watermark to image and Video by manipulating the pixel values, when the work was limited to image it was quite easy but I want to add watermark on video.

**I want to know that how can i process each frame of video and add some watermark(another little image) to it and again recombine it to form a video again??**

Comment: There are going to be three steps: 1. Decode to images. 2. Add watermark. 3. Re-encode to video.  Each of these steps range from tedious to painfully tedious to do yourself - find a library that does encoding/decoding for 1 and 3, and use your existing code to do number 2.

Comment: Thank You for your interest in it , But I want to know which library to use ?

Comment: For that, you might check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210641/pure-java-video-endcoding-decoding-libraries